# Need help categorizing data (based on 2 Columns in r)

Tags: r

I have 2 columns - one that has a number (Section) and the other one that says if its `good` or `bad` in `r`

Here is a sample data

```r
df <- data.frame(
  G_or_B = c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good"), 
  Section = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2, 3,3) 
)
```

I need a `barplot` that says for every section, how many `good` and how many `bad` it has. I'm new to r, but can understand pre-existing code good enough. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMzu8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using `base-r` you can do the following:

```r
barplot(table(df), legend.text = TRUE, beside = TRUE, yaxt="n", xlab = "Section", ylab = "Freq")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 3, 1), las = 1)
# You can set beside=FALSE, if you want the bars stacked.
```

## Output

[image: sample_out]

## Data

```r
df <- data.frame(G_or_B = c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good"), 
                 Section = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2, 3,3) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have the ggplot2 package installed because ggplot is a great package for creating graphs.

Here's the code to accomplish what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("G or B" = c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good"), 
                 "Section" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)  )   # This is your data frame

names(df)  # checking the variable names

ggplot(df, aes(x = Section, fill = G.or.B) )+  # Creates the bar graph with good / bad
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I wanted. And it worked. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I also want to display the number of Good or Bad for every section on the bar. How do I do this? Thanks!